# Firebase not logging user out

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I took the logout function from Firebase to logout a user that logs in. I can properly log in but I clearly cannot log out. I have tested this out many times but the log out function simply does not work. Any and all help would be much appreciated. The following is my code:

```ts
export class AuthService {
    private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
    private userDetails: firebase.User = null;

    constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { 
        this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;
        this.user.subscribe(
            (user) => {
                if (user) {
                    this.userDetails = user;
                    console.log(this.userDetails);
                }
                else {
                    this.userDetails = null;
                }
            }
        );
    }

  signInWithGoogle() {
      return this._firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(
          new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
      )
  }

  signup(email: string, password: string) {
      this._firebaseAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(value => {
              console.log('Success!', value);
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
          });    
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
      this._firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(value => {
              console.log('Nice, it worked!');
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
          });
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
      if (this.userDetails == null ) {
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
  }
  directToNext() {
      if (this.isLoggedIn){
          this.router.navigate(['/or-items/1']);
      }    
  }

  logout() {
      this._firebaseAuth.auth.signOut()
      .then((res) => this.router.navigate(['/']));
    }
  }
```

Then in the HTML:

```html
<script>
    import {AuthService} from' ./../AuthService';
    
    function  logout() {
        this.authService.logout();
    }
    
    function  isLoggedIn() {
        this.authService.isLoggedIn();
    }
 </script>
 
<span>
 <button mat-raised-button color="basic" (click)="logout()">
          logout
 </button>
</span>
```

I know that the user is not correctly being logged out because the firebase console indicates that the user is still logged in.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `AuthService.logout();` and `AuthService.isLoggedIn()`?

Comment: If not, you probably need to add `AuthService` to the page's constructor/init because `this.authService` isn't pointing to anything that I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qari,  AFAIK the Firebase console does not indicate whether the user is logged in or not.  I think what it shows is the last login date.

At least on the Android Firebase SDK, when one requests a signout, there is a callback that can be used to indicate whether the call was successful.  To be doubly sure, one can get the current user info again and verify that there is no current user. You may want to try along similar lines.

Comment: thank you for that information. That was very helpful. Do you know how I could check to confirm that the user has been logged out? I am having issues I want to use *ngIf= isLoggedIn() then show button. But, the button never disappears/appears considering the status of the loggin/out

Comment: I have used Firebase only with Java code (Android) and the solution there is what I described above.